# Evaluating an integral symbolically seems impossible

Tags: numerical-integration, fitting, symbolic, special-functions

I have an integral of general form

$$ i_n(z)=\dfrac{z^2}{K_2(z)}\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\left(x^2-1\right)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}}{x^{2n+1}}  \exp(-zx)  dx $$

$K_2(z)$ is the bessel function and $0.01 \leqslant z\leqslant 1000$.

```
in[z_]:= Assuming[Re[z]>0,(z^2/BesselK[2,z]) NIntegrate[((x^2-1)^(n+(3/2))/x^(2n+1)) Exp[-z x],{x,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision,AccuracyGoal -> 3]]
```

For reasons of analytical calculation, I would like to get symbolically the first four integrals $i_0$, $i_1$, $i_2$ and $i_3$ but MATHEMATICA does not do this. Do you have an idea please?

```
(* i0 *)
i0[z_]:= Assuming[Re[z]>0,(z^2/BesselK[2,z]) NIntegrate[((x^2-1)^(3/2)/x) Exp[-z x],{x,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision -> $MachinePrecision,AccuracyGoal -> 3]]

(* i1 *)
i1[z_]:= Assuming[Re[z]>0,(z^2/BesselK[2,z]) NIntegrate[((x^2-1)^(5/2)/x^3) Exp[-z x],{x,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision ->$MachinePrecision,AccuracyGoal -> 3]]

(* i2 *)
i2[z_]:= Assuming[Re[z]>0,(z^2/BesselK[2,z]) NIntegrate[((x^2-1)^(7/2)/x^5) Exp[-z x],{x,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision ->$MachinePrecision,AccuracyGoal -> 3]]

(* i3 *)
i3[z_]:= Assuming[Re[z]>0,(z^2/BesselK[2,z]) NIntegrate[((x^2-1)^(9/2)/x^7) Exp[-z x],{x,1,Infinity},WorkingPrecision ->$MachinePrecision,AccuracyGoal -> 3]]
```

Alternatively, can these four integrals be expressed numerically as a fite for $z$ values between 0.01 and 1000?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi. Just wanted to say that I think you should not have mentioned $z^2/K_2(z)$ at all here, it is irrelevant for your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

int1[n_Integer?NonNegative][z_] = Assuming[
  Re[z] > 0 && Element[n, NonNegativeIntegers],
  (z^2/BesselK[2, z])*Integrate[
    ((x^2 - 1)^(n + (3/2))/x^(2 n + 1)) Exp[-z*x],
    {x, 1, Infinity}]]

(* (2 Gamma[5/2 + n] MeijerG[{{}, {2 + n}}, {{-(1/2), 1, 3/2}, {}}, 
  z^2/4])/(Sqrt[π] BesselK[2, z]) *)
```

This expression requires high precision to evaluate successfully

```
tab = Table[int1[1][SetPrecision[50, prec]], {prec, 10, 70, 10}]

(* {0.*10^35, 0.*10^25, 0.*10^14, 
 0.*10^4, 0.25795, 0.25794538343534, 0.257945383435342238585179} *)

Precision /@ tab

(* {0., 0., 0., 0., 4.4595, 13.8895, 23.871} *)
```

For numeric integration

```
int2[n_Integer?NonNegative][z_Real?Positive] :=
 (z^2/BesselK[2, z])*NIntegrate[
   ((x^2 - 1)^(n + (3/2))/x^(2 n + 1)) Exp[-z*x],
   {x, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> Precision[z]]
```

`int2` requires less precision than `int1`

```
tab2 = int2[1] /@ {50., 50.0`10, 50.0`20, 50.0`30}

(* {0.257945, 0.25794539, 0.257945383435342239, 
  0.2579453834353422385851787618} *)

Precision /@ tab2

(* {MachinePrecision, 8.26731, 18.2673, 28.2673} *)

int1[3][1000.0`900] // N

(* 9.1906*10^-7 *)

int2[3][1000.0`100] // Quiet // N

(* 9.1906*10^-7 *)
```

**EDIT:** Approximations for large and small `z`

For large `z`

```
int3[n_Integer?NonNegative, z_?Positive] = Evaluate@
  Assuming[Element[n, NonNegativeIntegers],
   Asymptotic[(2*Gamma[5/2 + n]*MeijerG[{{}, {2 + n}}, 
             {{-(1/2), 1, 3/2}, {}}, z^2/4])/
      (Sqrt[Pi]*BesselK[2, z]), {z, Infinity, 3}] // FullSimplify]

(* (1/Sqrt[π])2^(-2 + n) z^(-3 - 
  n) (-3 (1 + n) (130 + n (410 + n (402 + n (178 + n (37 + 3 n))))) + 
   2 (1 + n) (55 + n (109 + n (55 + 9 n))) z - 8 (1 + n) (5 + 3 n) z^2 + 
   16 z^3) Gamma[5/2 + n] *)
```

Comparing with `int1`

```
Table[
  Grid[
   Join[
     {{StringForm["z = ``", z], SpanFromLeft},
      {n, int1, int3}},
     Table[
      {n, int1[n][SetPrecision[z, 900]], int3[n, z]}, {n, 0, 3}]] /.
    x_Real :> N[x],
   Frame -> All],
  {z, {1000., 200., 100.}}] // Column
```

[image]

For small `z`

```
int4[n_Integer?NonNegative, z_?Positive] = Evaluate@
  Assuming[Element[n, NonNegativeIntegers] && z > 0,
   Asymptotic[(2*Gamma[5/2 + n]*MeijerG[{{}, {2 + n}}, 
             {{-(1/2), 1, 3/2}, {}}, z^2/4])/
      (Sqrt[Pi]*BesselK[2, z]), {z, 0, 5}] // FullSimplify]

(* (Sqrt[π] z^4 Gamma[5/2 + n])/(3 n!) + 
 1/32 z (32 - 16 (1 + n) z^2 + 
    2 (-8 + 4 EulerGamma (1 + n)^2 - n (16 + 7 n)) z^4 + 
    z^4 ((3 + 4 n (2 + n)) HarmonicNumber[-(1/2) + n] + 8 n (2 + n) Log[z] + 
       Log[z^8/4])) *)
```

Comparing with `int1`

```
Table[
  Grid[
   Join[
    {{StringForm["z = ``", z], SpanFromLeft},
     {n, int1, int4}},
    Table[{n, int1[n][z], int4[n, z]}, {n, 0, 3}]],
   Frame -> All],
  {z, {0.01, 0.25, 0.5}}] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bob. Please have you a method to express these symbolic complex functions by simple fitted functions of z?

Comment: Thank you so much @BobHanlon. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 7):

> Do you have an idea

You can not do numerical integration because you had `z` inside the integral which had no numerical value. Adding `Assuming[Re[z]>0` does not help `NIntegrate`. It needs an actual numerical value.

One way is to do symbolic integration then use Table to generate the 4 values you wanted

```
 anti[n_] = Integrate[((x^2 - 1)^(n + (3/2))/x^(2 n + 1)) Exp[-z x], {x, 1, 
   Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
Table[(z^2/BesselK[2, z])*anti[n], {n, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `Integrate` gives condition on `n` and `z` which I did not show above. Here it is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you need to make sure that your `n` and `z` you use to evaluate this agree. In the Table command above I used different `n` because that is what you were using.

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. Please how to express these complex functions by simple fitted functions of z?